# Element API calling Module that integrates with third-party plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-elementapi, modules

This is probably a bit niche but anyone especially au fait with the element api here?

On project X I have a custom module within which I am referencing a service from another plugin (`bolden/google-maps-api`). If I access the module directly (eg via a controller or variable belonging to my module) then all works fine.

However - if I try and access my module service from within an element api endpoint, then the service doesn't work (or rather returns null when trying to access the third-party plugin/service).

For example, in my endpoint I am calling the service ($location is a string):

`$data = MyModule::getInstance()->ServiceName->ServiceMethod( $location );`

But this returns the following Response: `Call to a member function placeFromText() on null` (the stack trace highlights the corresponding line within my module/service), eg:

```
$googleMaps = GoogleMapsApi::getInstance();
$result = $googleMaps->googleMapsApiService->placeFromText( $place, 'geometry' );
```

The same query, when accessed within my module (eg a controller or variable), works fine and returns a data object from the Google Maps API (as expected).

Bit confused - anyone have any thoughts on why this service isn't accessible from my module when accessed via the element API?

Any thoughts on this issue would be much appreciated!

Cole

Comment: I don't have a fix in your particular case but I had the same problem once, this might put you on the way - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13533/3630 - This line "You can think of Services and Variables as two different APIs for a plugin – one is only made available to PHP (Services) and the other is only made available to Twig/templates (Variables)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use full namespaces in Element API because anything within those functions is out of scope. So you need to use the full path to the Google class.

```
$googleMaps = new \Vendor\Module\GoogleMapsApi();
```

Putting a "use" directive at the top of the file will not work.

I had the exact same problem and that resolved my issues immediately.